# Como puedo comprimir en un archivo .zip y despues borrar los archivos originales

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stored-procedure, csv, zip

Tengo un programa que llama un procedimiento almacenado el cual funciona bien.

El resultado de este, me da 10 archivos con el nombre de los diferentes proyectos.

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es poder comprimir esos 10 archivos y hacer uno solo .ZIP que contenga estos archivos y despues se puedan borrar todos los 10 archivos .CSV originales.

Como podria hacer esto?

Aqui esta mi codigo:

```
List<string> projectName = new List<string>();
List<string> category = new List<string>();
List<string> Subcategory = new List<string>();

int count = xml.GetElementsByTagName("projectName").Count;

for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    projectName.Add(xml.GetElementsByTagName("projectName")[i].InnerText);
    category.Add(xml.GetElementsByTagName("category")[i].InnerText);
    Subcategory.Add(xml.GetElementsByTagName("Subcategory")[i].InnerText);
}

for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    string outCsvFile = string.Format(@"C:\\temp\\{0}.csv", category[i] + " " + Subcategory[i]);

    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCmd.Connection = conn;
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "testStoredProcedure";
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectTitle", projectName[i]);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", category[i]);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubCategory", Subcategory[i]);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskType", "");
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskStatus", "");
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsBaseLanguage", 1);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RaterDemographics", "FirtName,LastName,Email,Adress");

    conn.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
    using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(outCsvFile))
    {
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
        {
            items.Add(reader.GetName(j));
        }
        file.WriteLine("\"" + string.Join("\",\"", items) + "\"");


        while (reader.Read())
        {
            items = new List<string>();
            for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
            {
                items.Add(reader[j].ToString());
            }
            file.WriteLine("\"" + string.Join("\",\"", items) + "\"");

        }

    }
    conn.Close();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder comprimir podrias usar las clases que incluye .net

[Cómo: Comprimir y extraer archivos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms404280(v=vs.110).aspx)

cuantas con la clase `ZipFile` para crear el zip

Ahora bien el tema es como generar el zip sin que se bloquen los archivos, para eso seguramente debas usar bastante bien el `using`, de esta forma cuando termines de armar el zip al salir de using se libera para poder eliminar el file

[Zip Archives in C# 5.0 (.NET 4.5)](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/974/zip-archives-csharp-dotnet)

importante es analizar como usa

```
 using (ZipArchive zipArchive =   ZipFile.Open(@"C:\Archive.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Read)){ ...
```

alli esta el using que comento para que al terminar de armar el zip se liberen los archivos, de esta forma podras eliminarlos

Answer (score 0):

Después de haber comprimido los archivos puedes agregar un loop para eliminarlos:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{        
  System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\\temp\\{0}.csv", category[i] + " " + Subcategory[i])
}
```